# Trying to get the prior days data in Big Query, not the last 24hours. Prior date: GETDATE()-1

Tags: date, google-bigquery

Thought this would be easy, 4 hours later and 20+ Google Searches...https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions

All I want to do is pull the prior days data from a view in Big Query. I have been able to pull the last 24 hours but that is not what I need. Obviously missing something obvious here! Help is much appreciated.

I have 2 fields to work with:

date = '2021-07-16'
UTCTimestamp = 2021-07-016 11:27:03 UTC

```
RUNS:
SELECT date, count(*)  FROM `marketing.163735831.GAHits`
WHERE UTCTimestamp >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP by date;

RESULTS:
7/16/21 200

RUNS:
SELECT date, count(*) FROM `marketing.163735831.GAHits`
WHERE UTCTimestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
GROUP by date;

RESULTS:
7/16/21 200

WHAT I NEED: EXP.
WHERE CAST([ActivityDate] AS DATE) >= (GETDATE() - 1)
RESULTS:
7/15/21 500
```

Comment: Your question references a "view", is it possible your view is defined to only pull the current day's data?

Comment: No, it goes back to 2018

Comment: I am not sure I am tracking.  What is your ActivityDate in relation to date and UTCTimestamp?  It may also help to see some example data and outputs.

Comment: The example is what I'm looking for using SQL Server SQL. Example: date = getdate()-1 ::OR:: WHERE CAST([UTCTimestamp] AS DATE) >= (GETDATE() - 1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you are looking for.  the sample data contains dates with matching hourly timestamps. The resulting query returns all timestamps associated with 'yesterday'.

```
with sample_dates as (
    select cast(ts as date) dt
    , ts
    from UNNEST(generate_timestamp_array('2021-07-01 00:00:00', '2021-07-30 23:59:00', INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) ts
)

select sample_dates.dt as data_date
    , sample_dates.ts
    , current_date() as current_date
from sample_dates 
where 1=1
# and sample_dates.dt = date_sub(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
and cast(sample_dates.ts as date) >= date_sub(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: I don't need to unnest, all of that is done in the view. All I need are the files for 7/15 any time stamp.

Comment: thats just for me to produce a sample set of data to work with., and give you a full working example.  I think the where clause(s) I have defined are what you are looking for based on what you have defined.

Comment: Thanks! @Daniel that returns todays and yesterdays data, that is the exact problem I'm trying to solve for. I only want the previous days data not all data for the prior one day period starting at the run time.

Answer (score 0):

I knew I was missing something simple:

```
WHERE CAST(UTCTimestamp as date) = DATETIME_SUB(current_date()-1, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```